# Digital data to digital signals with Non return to zero(NRZ)

Tags: signal, encoding

NRZ codes share the property that voltage level is constant during a bit interval. High level voltage = bit 1 and Low level voltage = bit 0.

A problem arises when there is a long sequence of 0s or 1s and the voltage level is maintained at the same value for a long time. This creates a problem on the recieving end because now, the clock synchronization is lost due to lack of any transitions and hence, it is difficult to determine the exact number of 0s or 1s in this sequence. Like this at the receiver side:-

[image]

My question is that clock pulse is given above there , so why clock synchronization is lost if long strings of 0's are there? For example first clock pulse we receive one zero, and second clock pulse we receive one zero and so on. We see that clock is pulsing either 0 or 1, so why synchronization is failed?

N. B. -- I am a student of computer science background , I don't understand electrical engineering, I have required to understand some basics encoding scheme to understand the physical layer of computer network. So please don't use too much technical term, I just need to understand the intuition.

Comment: The clock pulse shown is not transmitted with the data - just the data itself and with NRZ it can be difficult to reconstruct the clock. Especially if the receiver does not know the exact frequency of the data being transmitted.

Comment: @KevinWhite if receiver uses it's own clock for receiving the data then how synchronization will be lost?

Comment: The synchronization is not lost if clock is sent as in synchronous communications, but it will be lost if clock is not sent as in asynchronous communications.

Comment: @AlokMaity - unless you know (within certain accuracy) the phase and frequency of the transmitted clock the receiver cannot assure the it is in synchronism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the clock signal at the receiver, there is no issue. The clock continues to provide a timing reference for bits. The problem is that the receiver *doesn't* have the same clock as the transmitter. It has one that's approximately the same in frequency, but may drift apart from the transmitter and is *not* aligned in phase.

For example, suppose that the system's agreed-upon clock frequency is 1 MHz, so there's a bit every microsecond. Your example waveform would ideally have transmissions at1 μs, 2 μs, 3 μs, 5 μs, and 8 μs.

However, the receiver doesn't have the same 1 MHz clock. It must instead figure out the clock on its own, only from the incoming signal - this is done with the help of a [clock recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery) circuit.

Suppose that due to imperfections/temperature/etc, the transmitter clock actually ran slow, in our example 0.015 μs error per cycle (as a numerical example). This is not unexpected, since clock signals are made by real-world oscillators with real-world imperfections.

The transitions would then be at 1.015 μs, 2.03 μs, 3.045 μs, 5.075 μs, and 8.125 μs. The clock recovery circuit would detect this since it's seeing transitions later than expected, and it would adjust its local clock signal accordingly, to also run slow in sync with the transmitter clock. This is often done with a PLL (phase-locked loop) circuit.

If we had too many bits without a transition, it becomes impossible to recover the clock. For example, imagine that our transmitter sent out 100 zeros in a row. Over those 100 zeros, there are no transitions, so no feedback to re-align the receiver clock with the transmitter clock. If the transmitter clock were running at 1.015 μs per cycle instead of the intended 1 μs per cycle, these 100 zeros took 101.5 μs to transmit - without any transitions to use for time-keeping, the receiver actually detects either 101 or 102 zeros, and the transmitted data has been damaged.

On the other hand, if there were enough transitions during that time, then as the receiver and transmitter clocks drift apart from each other, the receiver clock can be adjusted.

(note to more advanced readers: The PLL can also drift off the necessary setpoint even if we don't slip by a whole bit between two transitions; the above is a simpler conceptual example that doesn't require us to consider the performance limitations of a clock-recovery circuit, but rather show a case where even the most ideal clock recovery circuit cannot recover a clock. Also, 15000 ppm of clock error is excessive, but it's used here for a numerical example).

Comment: @AlokMaity - Your ongoing requests for more information have exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore the comments so far have been moved to chat and should be continued there (if other site members want to continue replying, of course) - see link below. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135119/discussion-on-answer-by-nanofarad-digital-data-to-digital-signals-with-non-retur).

Comment: @AlokMaity - As I explained above, comments are no longer appropriate for your ongoing requests for more information. Your additional comments here will be deleted. If you have a problem using the chatroom then I can help to investigate that. However, your comments have tried to extend the topic beyond what is reasonable, and seem to be asking for the same explanations again & again. To be as clear as possible here: Please **stop** trying to ask for even more help in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @AlokMaity - After your earlier (now deleted) comment, I investigated & found why you can't use chat (and you know why too). Since you can't use chat & have used much more than a reasonable number of comments, your participation in this question has to stop as those are the only types of communication between site members available here. || In future Q / A, please be careful not to use comments excessively (leading to them being moved to chat) e.g. keep any follow-up clarification questions *tightly* constrained on the topic in that Q / A. Don't expand the topic. Show your own research. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For example UART communications use NRZ to send data, and there is no clock signal transmitted between two UARTs, so it is asynchronous communication.

And since the transmitter and receiver both use their own clocks that might have some tolerance or error between them, the data is resynchronized each frame. The data is sent with a start bit to start the reception of the following bits. And since the reception is only valid for the data frame from start bit to stop bit, the allowed tolerance between clocks in a 8-bit data frame is roughly 2%.

So if the UART did not add start and stop bits to resynchronize each byte, it would be impossible to stay in sync for more than one byte, or it would require the clocks to be very precise and bit rate to match very carefully.

Comment: @AlokMaity - Your ongoing requests for more information have exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore the comments so far have been moved to chat and should be continued there (if the answer's author wants to continue replying, of course) - see link below. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135118/discussion-on-answer-by-justme-digital-data-to-digital-signals-with-non-return-t).